# collision prediction in HTML5 canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision-detection, 2d-games

I am creating a minigame in HTML5 with canvas.

The problem I am facing now is that I have implemented a collision function, which is called "circleCollidesWithRectangle". This function should detect if the player ( yellow circle ) is about hitting any boundary when changing the selected direction. If it would hit than the prefered direction change shouldn't be applied, but the old direction should remain. Or if the player is in front of a boundary than the player should remin infront of the boundary and not hitting the boundary.

That is what I try to achieve, but now, if a boundary is in front of the player than the player is hitting the boundary and the preferred behaviour with the direction change is also not working properly.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const scoreEl = document.querySelector('#scoreEl');

//canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.width = innerWidth;
//canvas.height = innerHeight - 30;
canvas.height = 420;

class Boundary {
  static width = 40 * 0.8;
  static height = 40 * 0.8;
  constructor({position}) {
    this.position = position;
    this.width = 40 * 0.8;
    this.height = 40 * 0.8;
  }
  draw() {
  context.fillStyle = '#b871ff';         
   context.fillRect(this.position.x,this.position.y,this.width, this.height);
  }
}

class Player {
  constructor({position, velocity}) {
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.radius = 15 * 0.8;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
context.arc(this.position.x,this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
context.fillStyle = "yellow";
context.fill();
context.closePath();
  }
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
  }
}

class Ghost {
  constructor({position, velocity, color = 'red'}) {
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.radius = 15 * 0.8;
    this.color = color;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
context.arc(this.position.x,this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
context.fillStyle = this.color;
context.fill();
context.closePath();
  }
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
  }
}

class Pellet {
  constructor({position}) {
    this.position = position;
    this.radius = 5;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
context.arc(this.position.x,this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
context.fillStyle = "#b871ff";
context.fill();
context.closePath();
  }
}

let selectedDirection;
let score = 0;

const map = [
  ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
  ['-',' ','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','-'],
  ['-','.','-','.','-','-','-','.','-','.','-'],
  ['-','.','.','.','.','-',' ','.','.','.','-'],
  ['-','.','-','-',' ',' ',' ','-','-','.','-'],
  ['-','.',' ',' ',' ','-','.','.','.','.','-'],
  ['-','.','-',' ','-','-','-',' ','-','.','-'],
  ['-','.',' ',' ','.','-','.','.','.','.','-'],
  ['-','.','-','-','.','.','.','-','-','.','-'],
  ['-','.',' ',' ',' ','-','.','.','.','.','-'],
  ['-','.','-',' ','-','-','-',' ','-','.','-'],
  ['-','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.',' ','-'],
  ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
]

const pellets = []
const boundaries = [];
const ghosts = [
  new Ghost({
    position: {
      x: Boundary.width * 5 + Boundary.width / 2,
      y: Boundary.height + Boundary.height / 2
    },
    velocity: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  })
]

const player = new Player({
  position: {
    x: Boundary.width + Boundary.width / 2,
    y: Boundary.height + Boundary.height / 2
  },
  velocity: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }
})

map.forEach((row, i) => {
  row.forEach((symbol, j) => {
    switch (symbol) {
        case '-':
        boundaries.push(
          new Boundary({
            position: {
                x: Boundary.width * j,
                y: Boundary.height * i
              }
            })
        )
        break;
        case '.':
        pellets.push(
          new Pellet({
            position: {
                x: Boundary.width * j + Boundary.width / 2,
                y: Boundary.height * i + Boundary.height / 2
              }
            })
        )
        break;
    }
  })
})

function circleCollidesWithRectangle({
  circle,
  rectangle
}) {
  return(circle.position.y - circle.radius + circle.velocity.y <= rectangle.position.y + rectangle.height &&
         circle.position.x + circle.radius + circle.velocity.x >= rectangle.position.x &&
         circle.position.y + circle.radius + circle.velocity.y >= rectangle.position.y &&
         circle.position.x - circle.radius + circle.velocity.x <= rectangle.position.x + rectangle.width)
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

if(selectedDirection === "up") {
  for (let i=0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (circleCollidesWithRectangle({
      circle: {...player, velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: -1
      }},
      rectangle: boundary
    })){
    player.velocity.y = 0;
    break;
    } else {
    player.velocity.x = 0;
    player.velocity.y = -1;
    }
  }  
} else if (selectedDirection === "down") {
  for (let i=0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (circleCollidesWithRectangle({
      circle: {...player, velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 1
      }},
      rectangle: boundary
    })){
    player.velocity.y = 0;
    break;
    } else {
    player.velocity.x = 0;
    player.velocity.y = 1;
    }
  }  
} else if (selectedDirection === "left") {
  for (let i=0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (circleCollidesWithRectangle({
      circle: {...player, velocity: {
        x: -1,
        y: 0
      }},
      rectangle: boundary
    })){
    player.velocity.x = 0;
    break;
    } else {
    player.velocity.y = 0;
    player.velocity.x = -1;
    }
  }
} else if (selectedDirection === "right") {
  for (let i=0; i < boundaries.length; i++) {
    const boundary = boundaries[i];
    if (circleCollidesWithRectangle({
      circle: {...player, velocity: {
        x: 1,
        y: 0
      }},
      rectangle: boundary
    })){
    player.velocity.x = 0;
    break;
    } else {
    player.velocity.y = 0;
    player.velocity.x = 1;
    }
  }  
}

  for (let i = pellets.length - 1; 0 < i; i--) {
  const pellet = pellets[i]
  pellet.draw();
    
  if (Math.hypot(pellet.position.x - player.position.x, pellet.position.y - player.position.y) < pellet.radius + player.radius) {
      pellets.splice(i, 1)
      score += 10;
      scoreEl.innerHTML = score;
    }
}

  boundaries.forEach((boundary) => {
  boundary.draw();

//collision detection    
  if (circleCollidesWithRectangle({
    circle: player,
    rectangle: boundary
  })){
  player.velocity.x = 0;
  player.velocity.y = 0;
  }
})

player.update();
ghosts.forEach(ghost => {
 ghost.update(); 

 const collisions = [];
 boundaries.forEach(boundary => {
  if (
    !collisions.includes('right') &&
    circleCollidesWithRectangle({
    circle: {...ghost, velocity: {
      x: 1,
      y: 0
    }},
    rectangle: boundary
  })){
    collisions.push('right');
  }
  if (
    !collisions.includes('left') &&
    circleCollidesWithRectangle({
    circle: {...ghost, velocity: {
      x: -1,
      y: 0
    }},
    rectangle: boundary
  })){
    collisions.push('left');
  }
  if (
    !collisions.includes('up') &&
    circleCollidesWithRectangle({
    circle: {...ghost, velocity: {
      x: 0,
      y: -1
    }},
    rectangle: boundary
  })){
    collisions.push('up');
  }
  if (
    !collisions.includes('down') &&
    circleCollidesWithRectangle({
    circle: {...ghost, velocity: {
      x: 0,
      y: 1
    }},
    rectangle: boundary
  })){
    collisions.push('down');
  }
 })
})
}

document.getElementById("btn-direction-up").addEventListener("click", () => {
 selectedDirection = "up";
console.log(player.velocity)
})
document.getElementById("btn-direction-down").addEventListener("click", () => {
 selectedDirection = "down";
console.log(player.velocity)
})
document.getElementById("btn-direction-left").addEventListener("click", () => {
 selectedDirection = "left";
console.log(player.velocity)
})
document.getElementById("btn-direction-right").addEventListener("click", () => {
 selectedDirection = "right";
console.log(player.velocity)
})  

animate();
```

```css
.gamification-body {
  background-color: #3c0078 !important;
}
.direction-btn {
  color: #3c0078;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #b871ff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.gamification-body #trustbadge-container-98e3dadd90eb493088abdc5597a70810, .gamification-body #shopify-section-announcement-bar {
 display: none !important
}
#custom-gamification-btns-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 30px 0 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}
#custom-gamification-direction-btns-row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
#custom-gamification-direction-btns-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: white; font-family: obviously-narrow;font-weight: 800; font-size: 20px;margin: 6px;">
  <span>Score:</span><span id="scoreEl">0</span>
</p>
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="custom-gamification-btns-container">
  <div id="custom-gamification-direction-btns-row">
    <div class="direction-btn" id="btn-direction-left">left</div>
    <div id="custom-gamification-direction-btns-column">
      <div class="direction-btn" id="btn-direction-up">up</div>
      <div class="direction-btn" id="btn-direction-down">down</div>
    </div>
    <div class="direction-btn" id="btn-direction-right">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if any of the corners collides with the circle, use the Pythagorean theorem to check if the distance of the corner to the center of the circle is smaller (or equal?) than circle radius.

Checking if any of the edges collides without any of the corners colliding: For horizontal edges you need to check whether both x1 < X < x2 and |y - Y| <= R , where x1 < x2 are X coordinates of rectangle boundary, y is y position of horizontal edge, (X,Y) is circle center and R is its radius. || means absolute value.

And for vertical edges you need to similarly check whether both y1 < Y < y2 and |x - X| <= R